# TikZ node: How to decrease vertical space between two lines of text?

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, nodes, text

Assumed we have some simple code to display text above a `brace` styled node in `TikZ`.

---

**Minimum working example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=1]

\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,raise=4pt},yshift=0pt]
(20,50) -- (80,50) node [black,midway,align=center,yshift=0.75cm] {\footnotesize Test\\\footnotesize Test};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image: Screenshot of the result]

---

**Description of the issue:**

As you can see, the empty space between those two text lines is very huge and therefore doesn't look very nice.

How can I decrease the white space between two text lines?

Comment: The correct usage is `font=\footnotesize` as in: `\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=1]

\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,raise=4pt},yshift=0pt]
(20,50) -- (80,50) node
[black,midway,align=center,yshift=0.75cm,font=\footnotesize] {Test\\ Test};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}` If you want to further decrease the distance, use e.g. a node content of the sort `{Test\\[-0.2em] Test}`.

Comment: @marmot: Once more: Thanks you very much! :-) You can post this as an answer...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The appropriate usage for having the font in `\footnotesize` (or any other size like `\small`, `\large` etc.) is either

```
font=\footnotesize
```

or

```
node font=\footnotesize
```

As far as I can tell, here is no visible difference in the output of these two options in the case of your MWE. It can, however, be useful to have two font commands, so you may say `\tikzset{every node/.append style={font=\sffamily}}` and add to a specific node `node font=\footnotesize` such that the node font of this node will then be both sans serif and small.

Applied to your MWE, you could do

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=1]

\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,raise=4pt},yshift=0pt]
(20,50) -- (80,50) node
[black,midway,align=center,yshift=0.75cm,font=\footnotesize] {Test\\ Test};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to further decrease the distance, use e.g. a node content of the sort `{Test\\[-0.2em] Test}`. This tuning is always available, regardless of the size. It will me conceivably more important if different lines of the text have different font sizes.